Pandas operation to get a new column from a shifted value of another column and this new one
Assume a test dataframe
data = {'A': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
        'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    A   B
0   10  1
1   20  2
2   30  3
3   40  4
4   50  5
5   60  6
6   70  7
7   80  8
8   90  9
9   100 10

I'd like to calculate column C: Ci = (Ci-1 * Ai-1 + Bi * (Ai - Ai-1))
I've tried this:
df["C"] = df["B"]
df["C"] = (df["C"].shift(1, fill_value=0) * df["A"].shift(1, fill_value=0) + df["B"] * (df["A"] - df["A"].shift(1, fill_value=0)))/df["A"]

and got this result
    A   B   C
0   10  1   1.000000
1   20  2   1.500000
2   30  3   2.333333
3   40  4   3.250000
4   50  5   4.200000
5   60  6   5.166667
6   70  7   6.142857
7   80  8   7.125000
8   90  9   8.111111
9   100 10  9.100000

but expected result is:
    A   B   C
0   10  1   1
1   20  2   1,5
2   30  3   2
3   40  4   2,5
4   50  5   3
5   60  6   3,5
6   70  7   4
7   80  8   4,5
8   90  9   5
9   100 10  5,5

Is there any way of doing this without iterating over each row?

Do this instead
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
        'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["C"] = 0.0

df.at[0, "C"] = df.at[0, "B"]

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.at[i, "C"] = (df.at[i-1, "C"] * df.at[i-1, "A"] + df.at[i, "B"] * (df.at[i, "A"] - df.at[i-1, "A"])) / df.at[i, "A"]

print(df)

which gives you

     A   B    C
0   10   1  1.0
1   20   2  1.5
2   30   3  2.0
3   40   4  2.5
4   50   5  3.0
5   60   6  3.5
6   70   7  4.0
7   80   8  4.5
8   90   9  5.0
9  100  10  5.5


